# JNLP generated from PHP fails

Tags: php, java-web-start

I have a very odd problem. I have a JNLP file that works just fine when a property is hand-edited:

```
<property name="javaws.username" value="dummy" />
```

But when the same property is generated from php with a real value like this:

```
<property name="javaws.username" value="fb1331463499" />
```

It shows up as empty at runtime.  I've examined the jnlp file in Xcode to look for control characters but Xcode show none.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the real value when hand-editing? If yes and if it works, try running a diff between the two files.

Comment: Yes but i hdnt thought o diff, thanks!

Comment: Ahaha!  opendiff says there is an extra character at the end of the PHP generated line.  Now i need to figure out why echo is doing that and make it stop...

Comment: Its a ^J.  For some reason echo is inserting that ven though i cant find any mention of it in the php docs :(  Anyone know how to supress that??

Comment: Im goign to star ta new questio nspecificly abt that damn ^J

Answer (score 1):

Still had problems.

I traced it down at last to this line in the JNLP:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://fgdztgab.joyent.us/snowmen" href="snowman.jnlp">
```

Jnlp files are a weird hack.  They basically reload themselves off the href parameter if it is available. This allows them to use their own caching and versioning mechanism for the jnlp file.  Unfortunately, it meant it was reloading WITHOUT the get parameters.  I probably could have added the get parameters to the href, but since its optional anyway I just took it out.

That fixed the problem.

Moral of the story: be VARY aware of what href does if you include it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by going to heredoc format which moves the unwanted ctrl-J to the end of the file.

Not a great soln but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The href causes the jnlp file to be loaded from that URL (relative to the codebase or fully qualified), which if you are generating a dynamic jnlp, will supercede the dynamic information.  In that case you can leave out the JNLP href to prevent that reload, but just fyi - from the JNLP Tag Reference Page - http://lopica.sourceforge.net/ref.html:

> Note, that Java Web Start needs href to list your app in the Web Start
>   Application Manager.